# Javascript - No me suma los inputs de los divs clonados

Tags: javascript

Luego de mucho practicar con **[ESTE script](https://jsfiddle.net/puro8xke/1)** (soy novato nivel 0), he logrado sumar valores de los inputs de un div determinado, **pero ahora que los estoy clonando a otro div** no me suma los inputs clonados.

**[VER DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/owxsL31y/6/)**

**Pregunta 1:**

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal, si al script le estoy pidiendo que lea y sume los inputs contenidos **en el div con la clase derecha**...?

**Pregunta 2:**

¿Hay alguna forma de **sumar los inputs clonados** y que el resultado de la suma **se actualice dinámicamente**, sin tener que hacer click en **"Ver Total"**...?

Muchas gracias...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function sumInputs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valores = $('.derecha').children('input');
    var suma = 0;
    $.each(valores, function() {
      valor = $(this).val();
      suma += Number(valor);
    });

    valores = document.getElementById('total');
    $(valores).val(suma);
  }

  $('#sumup').on('click', sumInputs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="add-prod-1" type="num" value="199">
<input name="add-prod-1" type="num" value="249">
<input name="add-prod-1" type="num" value="69">

<input name="total" id="total">
<a id='sumup'>Ver total</a>
```

Comment: verifica la linea `var valores = $('.derecha').children('input');` estas buscando dentro de la class `derecha` todos los `inputs` asociados

Comment: Hola JackNavaRow ... Claro. Lo que estoy buscando es sumar SÓLO los inputs que se van clonando en el div con la clase derecha (y no todos los inputs del html). Es lo que no me sale...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar por elementos de clase, revisa el codigo cualquier duda agrega un comentario

```js
const suma= function(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("add-prod-1");
let sum=0;
for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
{
console.log(x[i].value)
   sum += parseFloat(x[i].value);
}
console.log(sum);
return sum;
}

console.log(suma());

document.getElementById("total").value=suma();
```

```html
<input class="add-prod-1" type="num" value="199">
<input class="add-prod-1" type="num" value="249">
<input class="add-prod-1" type="num" value="69">

<input name="total" id="total">
<p id='sumup'>Ver total</p>
```

Comment: Gracias Miguel Zarate. Edité el DEMO (Ve aquí:  https://jsfiddle.net/owxsL31y/8/ ), pero no funciona como yo desearía, ya que el script me suma los inputs, pero TODOS los inputs y NO los inputs clonados, que es lo que estoy buscando. O sea, si tengo 1000 inputs en el html me los sumaria a todos, y lo que estoy buscando es que SOLO me sume los inputs clonados. No sé si me explico...

Comment: como haces una distincion entre los originales y los clonados?

Comment: Y eso es lo que no me sale... Si miras el demo original (sin clonar), el script sólo suma los inputs del div "derecha" ( var valores = $('#derecha').children('input'); ) VER DEMO AQUI ( https://jsfiddle.net/puro8xke/1 ) donde el div izquierda está en display none, pero lo que ahora busco esá saliendo del div "productos", también en display none, y el script los clona en el div con la clase derecha. Los inputs de la clase derecha son los que quiero sumar, no todos los inputs del html...